# Obtaining Invitation State Without Directory.Read.All API Permissions

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, blazor

I want to retrieve the invitation state, but I lack API permissions for Directory.Read.All. Is there a viable solution to obtain the property

[image]

.Invitations[azureInvitation.Id.ToString()].GetAsync();

I tried the above code. It is throwing an exception

Error details
[image]

Comment: Could you share more code and details about  the exception?

Comment: You can try with the **User.Invite.All** API permission and granting access to fetch the details of user invitations.

Comment: @Divya, Could you confirm whether your requirement is to retrieve invitation state of users like this in Blazor app https://i.imgur.com/sxukCS2.png?

Comment: Hi @VenkatV I have the User.Invite.All permission. I am not able to retrieve the invitation status.

Comment: @Sridevi, yes exactly Devi.

Comment: @user2250152 Please see the error detail in the snap

Comment: You need to use this graph query: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Guest'&$select=id,displayName,externalUserState`

Answer (score 0):

> You can fetch **Invitation State** of users by granting `User.Read.All` permission of *Application* type in your app registration.

I have below list of guest users in my Microsoft Entra tenant with *Invitation State* like this:

[image]

I registered one application and granted **`User.Read.All`** permission of **Application** type in it:

[image]

To fetch these details with **Invitation state** property from my Blazor app, I used below `.Net` code:

*UserData.Razor:*

```cs
@page "/userdata"
@using Azure.Identity
@using Microsoft.Graph
@using Microsoft.Graph.Models
@using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors
@rendermode InteractiveServer


<h3>Graph Data</h3>

@if (Users != null)
{
    foreach (var user in Users)
    {
        <div>
            <p>Name: @user.DisplayName</p>
            <p>User ID: @user.Id</p>
            <p>Invitation State: @user.ExternalUserState</p>
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <p>Error fetching data from Microsoft Graph.</p>
}

@code {
    private IEnumerable<User> Users;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var clientId = "appId";
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var result = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "userType eq 'Guest'";
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName", "externalUserState" };
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
                requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "Eventual");
            });

            Users = result.Value;
        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            // Handle error as needed
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To fetch these details via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), you can run below query by granting consent to `User.Read.All` permission:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Guest'&$select=id,displayName,externalUserState
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Devi.  Admin consent is required for the User.Read.All API. However not able to get that due to security purposes

Comment: `User.Read.All` is the least privileged permission compared to `Directory.Read.All` to fetch user details. You must have at least that permission consented for fetching required details.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no other way. You need to have at least `User.Read.All` permission consented.